# Getting "Integrator key not found" while trying to download the document from DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I can able to create envelope and send the document to the recipient to get the eSignature. After the document is completed when i try to download the document

Envelope envelope = envelopesApi.getEnvelope(accountId,envelopeId);
byte[] results = envelopesApi.getDocument(accountId,envelopeId,"33");

Getting **Error!!!  com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code 400 with response Body: '{"errorCode":"PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED","message":"The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. Invalid account specified for user."}'**

***Create Envelope (Working fine with JWT)***

```
package com.sripy.demo;


import com.docusign.esign.api.AccountsApi;
import com.docusign.esign.api.EnvelopesApi;
import com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient;
import com.docusign.esign.client.auth.OAuth.OAuthToken;
import com.docusign.esign.client.auth.OAuth.UserInfo;
import com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException;
import com.docusign.esign.model.*;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

/**
 * Starter class for JWTConsoleApp application.
 */

public class JWTConsoleAppCreateEnvelope {

    static String DevCenterPage = "https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent";

    /**
     * Application entry point.
     *
     * @param args application command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String signerEmail = "******@yahoo.com";
        String signerName = "sriram sundararajan";
        String ccEmail = "******@gmail.com";
        String ccName = "John Doe";

        String className = "javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder";

        try {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
            String classPath = clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString();
            System.out.println("Loaded " + className + " from: " + classPath);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Class " + className + " not found!");
        }

        try {
// Get access token and accountId
            ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
            apiClient.setOAuthBasePath("account-d.docusign.com");
            ArrayList<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
            scopes.add("signature");
            scopes.add("impersonation");
            scopes.add("envelope_read");
            scopes.add("envelope_send");
            scopes.add("envelope_write");


            byte[] privateKeyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/...../src/main/resources/privatekey"));
            OAuthToken oAuthToken = apiClient.requestJWTUserToken("*****", "*****", scopes, privateKeyBytes, 3600);
            String accessToken = oAuthToken.getAccessToken();
            UserInfo userInfo = apiClient.getUserInfo(accessToken);
            apiClient.setAccessToken(accessToken, Long.valueOf("3600"));

            String accountId = userInfo.getAccounts().get(0).getAccountId();

// Check account association
            AccountsApi accountsApi = new AccountsApi(apiClient);
            AccountInformation accountInfo = accountsApi.getAccountInformation(accountId);


// Create envelopeDefinition object
            EnvelopeDefinition envelope = new EnvelopeDefinition();
            envelope.setEmailSubject("Please sign this document set");
            envelope.setStatus("sent");

// Create tabs object
            SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
            signHere.setDocumentId("1");
            signHere.setPageNumber("1");
            signHere.setXPosition("191");
            signHere.setYPosition("148");
            Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
            tabs.setSignHereTabs(Arrays.asList(signHere));
// Set recipients
            Signer signer = new Signer();
            signer.setEmail(signerEmail);
            signer.setName(signerName);
            signer.recipientId("1");
            signer.setTabs(tabs);
            CarbonCopy cc = new CarbonCopy();
            cc.setEmail(ccEmail);
            cc.setName(ccName);
            cc.recipientId("2");
            Recipients recipients = new Recipients();
            recipients.setSigners(Arrays.asList(signer));
            recipients.setCarbonCopies(Arrays.asList(cc));
            envelope.setRecipients(recipients);

// Add document
            Document document = new Document();
            document.setDocumentBase64("VGhhbmtzIGZvciByZXZpZXdpbmcgdGhpcyEKCldlJ2xsIG1vdmUgZm9yd2FyZCBhcyBzb29uIGFzIHdlIGhlYXIgYmFjay4=");
            document.setName("doc1.txt");
            document.setFileExtension("txt");
            document.setDocumentId("1");
            envelope.setDocuments(Arrays.asList(document));

// Send envelope
            apiClient.addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
            EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, envelope);
            System.out.println("Successfully sent envelope with envelopeId " + results.getEnvelopeId());

        } catch (ApiException exp) {
            if (exp.getMessage().contains("consent_required")) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Consent required, please provide consent in browser window and then run this app again.");
//Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=impersonation%20signature&client_id=" + prop.getProperty("clientId") + "&redirect_uri=" + DevCenterPage));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.print("Error!!! ");
                    System.out.print(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Error!!! ");
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

***Download Document (Same like above code except its calling download document)***

```
package com.sripy.demo;


import com.docusign.esign.api.AccountsApi;
import com.docusign.esign.api.EnvelopesApi;
import com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient;
import com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException;
import com.docusign.esign.client.auth.OAuth.OAuthToken;
import com.docusign.esign.client.auth.OAuth.UserInfo;
import com.docusign.esign.model.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Starter class for JWTConsoleApp application.
 */

public class JWTConsoleAppDownloadDocument {

    static String DevCenterPage = "https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent";

    /**
     * Application entry point.
     *
     * @param args application command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String signerEmail = "******@yahoo.com";
        String signerName = "sriram sundararajan";
        String ccEmail = "******@gmail.com";
        String ccName = "John Doe";


        try {
// Get access token and accountId
            ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
            apiClient.setOAuthBasePath("account-d.docusign.com");
            ArrayList<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
            scopes.add("signature");
            scopes.add("impersonation");
            scopes.add("envelope_read");
            scopes.add("envelope_send");
            scopes.add("envelope_write");


            byte[] privateKeyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/...../src/main/resources/private.key"));
            OAuthToken oAuthToken = apiClient.requestJWTUserToken("******", "*******", scopes, privateKeyBytes, 3600);
            String accessToken = oAuthToken.getAccessToken();
            UserInfo userInfo = apiClient.getUserInfo(accessToken);
            apiClient.setAccessToken(accessToken, Long.valueOf("3600"));

            String accountId = userInfo.getAccounts().get(0).getAccountId();
            String envelopeId = "3e07c8c9-7db7-47c4-a83f-f03bf229f7f7";

            downloadDoc(apiClient, envelopeId, accountId);

        } catch (ApiException exp) {
            if (exp.getMessage().contains("consent_required")) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Consent required, please provide consent in browser window and then run this app again.");
//Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=impersonation%20signature&client_id=" + prop.getProperty("clientId") + "&redirect_uri=" + DevCenterPage));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.print("Error!!! ");
                    System.out.print(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Error!!! ");
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void downloadDoc(ApiClient apiClient, String envelopeId, String accountId) {
        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);

        try {
            Envelope envelope = envelopesApi.getEnvelope(accountId, envelopeId);
            System.out.println(envelope.getAnySigner());
            byte[] results = envelopesApi.getDocument(accountId, envelopeId, "33");

            String dirPathString = "/...../src/main/resources/";
            String fileName = "DocuSign_POC_Signer_final.pdf";
            File f = new File(dirPathString + fileName);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
// Starting writing the bytes in it
            os.write(results);

        } catch (ApiException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Downloaded successfully");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to indicate that you're specifying the wrong account Id for the request. Can you confirm that the account Id you're passing is the same one you've used to create the envelope?

Comment: I am using the same java code which I used to create the envelope. Didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you get this code from quickstart?

Comment: This can also be that you use developer account vs. production account

Comment: What do you mean the same code? the code should be downloading an envelope, so it has to be different code. can you share the code you use?

Comment: did you instantiate envelopesAPI the same way exactly ?

Comment: Hi @InbarGazit what I meant was, the way how I was doing the authorization to create the envelope. The same way I was doing to download the document also. Yes I got this code from quick start.

Comment: So, you got quickstart, and you didn't change it, and try to run the example to download documents and get this error?

Comment: If you did change it - can you share your full code?

Comment: Hi @InbarGazit Added all the codes for creating envelopes and downloading the document.

Comment: So you can consistently run the first code - no error, and every time you run the second part - error?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong, only need the first two (signature, impersonation) the last 3 you have in there are invalid.

```
       scopes.add("signature");
        scopes.add("impersonation");
        scopes.add("envelope_read");
        scopes.add("envelope_send");
        scopes.add("envelope_write");
```